# Microsoft Excel - Generating random time invtervals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of employees around 30. I need to create a simple table that will assign them a specific time that they are to be on the phone and 24 hours later excel will automatically(randomly) change the time they are to be on the phone 
example

```
        mon   tue  wed  thu  fri
John   8-9
Sam    9-10
Debbie 10-11
Susan  11-12
Josh   12-1
sean   1-2
```

call times are 1 hour intervals between 8am and 6pm:

> 8-9, 9-10, 10-11, 11-12, 12-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6

What formula would take these times and automatically change them randomly every 24 hours through out the week?

Comment: You want 10 periods (1 hour each) to randomly be distributed over 30 employees 5 days per week. No regard as to if they have the same time as another on the same day and no regard as to whether or not you have coverage from 8-6? Or are there some other requirements you haven't told us.

Comment: I'm curious if that's a real world timesheet management question? -Hey boss, what's with the weird schedules? -The HAT has decided so!

Comment: @mtone "we leave the scheduling up to `Ayn Rand()` around here!"

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you do not want overlapping hours with the same day (one employee always on the phone), so starting from Raystafarian's suggestion, I'd make a separate list of shifts that are assigned a number.

```
Order  Schedule
=RAND()  9-10
=RAND()  10-11
=RAND()  11-12
=RAND()  12-1
=RAND()  1-2
=RAND()  1-3
=RAND()  
=RAND()  
=RAND()  // Since you have more employees than schedules, 
=RAND()  // copy formula to as many blank results as you have employees (30).
```

Then, do a **manual** sort by the Order column, and you'll end up with 30 [randomized results](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip093.shtml):

```
Order    Schedule
 0.3      <blank>
 0.4     1-3
 0.5      <blank>
 ..      <blank>
 ..      9-10
```

Now make a new table with your list of employees and use a simple formula to refer to the random schedule results, like this, so whenever you sort the values again, they will align (randomly) in front of each employee.

```
Employee  Today's schedule
 John    =B2
 Jane    =B3
 ..      =B4
 ..      =B5
 ..      =B6
```

Resulting in something like this:

```
Employee  Today's schedule
 John    <blank>
 Jane    12-1
 ..      <blank>
 ..      3-4
 ..      9-10
```

At this point, it's important that you **manually** copy those values (Paste Special...As Values) into a fixed daily schedule table like in your question, otherwise any new sort will replace your results permanently. Also make your that both employees lists always match in the same order.

Notice I highlighted the word **manual** twice. If you would like to automate these tasks you will need a VBA macro to do so, since there's no formula to automatically sortg or automatically copy formulas into fixed values somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just generate a random start time? Employees will know it's for 1 hour.
`=randbetween(8,17)` will generate a start time between 8am and 5pm (24 hour time format)